# How to manage further development on a Github collaboration after a pull request but before upstream merge

Tags: git, github

Although I use Git to manage my own projects I'm new to collaborating on Github and I'm slightly confused by how to manage my work.

Here's what I've done and where I'm up to:

- On Github made a fork of a repository
- Cloned it to my desktop PC
- Added the upstream to the original repository with: `git remote add upstream http_url.git`
- Created a new branch, made my changes, committed them
- Pushed my branch with: `git push origin my_branch`
- On Github, in my fork, switched to the branch that just got pushed and created a pull request

All well and good. The owner of the original repository thanked me for the pull request and said that he's away and wouldn't be able to check and merge until late next week.

I followed sensible practice and made changes to just one aspect of the code. However there are a couple of other things I'd like to do as well and issue pull requests for - but I am confused as to how best to manage it with git.

Normally, being happy with the branch, I'd merge it with master and keep going. But I'm not sure if that's what I should do. Should I instead create a new branch off the branch I've already pushed and develop in there? I'm not exactly sure what will happen when I `fetch upstream` after my pull request is accepted and merged into the original repository.

How should I manage further development? Please note that the development work I wish to do requires the changes which I've already made and that the owner of the original repository gave the go ahead for the changes I'm making before I started and, since they are well written and work, I have every expectation that my pull request will be accepted and merged when he gets back. Also I do not want to wait until the end of next week to continue my development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the branch that you have pushed and created the pull request is `A` and you have made `n` number of commits to it. So with respect to master it looks like this:

```
commit a1
commit a2
... ...
... ...
commit an
```

If you push more commits in this branch the pull request will automatically get updated. So if you want new changes to be merged with this pull request then there is nothing to do except pushing new commits here.

Now, let's say you don't want to add other things in this pull request and new changes require changes made in this branch (i.e. commits `a1 a2 ... an`). Here you can create a new branch `B` from `A` and make new commits `b1 b2 ... bn` here. So with respect to `A` branch `B` looks like this:

```
Branch B with respect to A
commit b1
commit b2
... ...
commit bn
```

But with respect to `master` branch B looks like this:

```
Branch B with respect to master
commit a1
commit a2
...
commit an
commit b1
commit b2
...
commit bn
```

Note that `a1 a2 ... an` are there since `B` was created from `A` and `A` is not merged to `master` yet.

Now `A` is merged to `master` in github by the owner of the main repository. If you fetch `upstream` after that commits `a1 a2 ... an` will be present in `upstream/master` but not in your local `master`. To get then in your local master you have to merge that in your local branch.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
```

After you merged `upstream/master` to local `master`, i.e. after `a1 a2 ... an` becomes available in `master` commits `a1 a2 ... an` will automatically get removed from `B`.

```
Branch B with respect to master after upstream/master is merged to master
commit b1
commit b2
...
commit bn
```

Now pull request from `B` will contain only this changes and they will be ready to be merged.

However, there is a catch in this. If you made more changes to `A` after you created `B` from it, i.e. new commits `an+1 an+2 ... an+m` are pushed to `A` before it get merged, then you will need these commits in `B` too. If that is the case then you can do [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) and [interactive rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase-i) `B` onto `A` (or onto `master` after A is merged). Please get familiar with rebase as that is the most powerful tool to do this kind of work.

**Warning**: be careful with `rebase`. It's easy to mess things up with this if used in wrong way. It's better to experiment with some test branches before trying it on real working branch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `feature` to be the name of the branch instead of `my_branch`. "upstream repo" means the repo represented by `http_url.git`.

> Normally, being happy with the branch, I'd merge it with master and keep going. But I'm not sure if that's what I should do. Should I instead create a new branch off the branch I've already pushed and develop in there?

Yes, that would work very well with future changes on `master` of the upstream repo. One example for this is another developer's PR getting merged before yours.

> How should I manage further development? Please note that the development work I wish to do requires the changes

```
(feature branch)
-commit1--commit2--commit3
                        \ (pr)
------------------------master
```

Say this is the current state of your development flow. The admin for the upstream repo made some comments and you had to push some more changes on that `feature` branch. Since you've branched off from `feature` for working on your next addition, you will end up with different histories on `feature` branch, and the new one you're working on.

```
(new feature branch)
-commit1--commit2--commit3--newcommit1--newcommit2
                        /
-commit1--commit2--commit3--commit4--commit5
                                      / (pr)
---(possibly other PRs getting merged)--master
```

Above picture will be the current state. Now, next step would be to figure out how to get the latest changes from the `feature` branch to the new feature branch (specifically, commits `commit4` and `commit5`). The two ways to do this would be either use `git rebase` or `git merge`. This is the sequence of steps I'd follow:

1. Go back to `master` branch
2. Fetch all the changes
3. Go to `new feature` branch
4. Run `git rebase master` on it

This will involve doing a force push to your GitHub remote branch since the current history of the `new feature` branch will have changed. Some developers don't like it for this reason.

Second way is to use `git merge`. 1 to 3 steps are the same. Step 4 would involve `git merge master` command. After running this and pushing to your remote's branch, if you compare the `master` and `new feature` branches, the changes will include only the `newcommit1` and `newcommit2` commits.

This strategy lets you continue your development workflow in the case you've mentioned. This only considers the case where your changes eventually get merged.